# I am not Getting Any Errors but When i am trying to click on Form my form Type Mouse does not appear

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

My form is Getting no Errors on Chrome Developers Error code but i am not getting and Text field or anything in my forms it is a very easy task but it had become a headache for me i will be very Helpfull if you help me with this

```
 <section class="reservation">
        <img class="img-responsive section-icon hidden-sm hidden-xs" src="{{ asset('frontend/images/icons/reserve_color.png') }}">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class=" section-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                            <form class="reservation-form" method="post" action="{{ route('resrvation.reserve') }}">
                                      {{ csrf_field() }}

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" name="name" id="name"
                                               placeholder="  &#xf007;  Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" id="email"  placeholder="  &#xf1d8;  e-mail">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="tel" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" name="phone" id="phone"  placeholder="  &#xf095;  Phone">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" name="dateandtime" id="datetimepicker1" placeholder="&#xf017;  Time">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <textarea type="text" name="message" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" id="message" rows="3"  placeholder="  &#xf086;  We're listening"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-reservation">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></span>
                                        Make a reservation
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4 or is it an older version?

Answer (score 0):

Just added BS cdn and copied your code. Everything looks fine and i see all the fields, did you include CDN as required??

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="reservation">
  <img class="img-responsive section-icon hidden-sm hidden-xs" src="{{ asset('frontend/images/icons/reserve_color.png') }}">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class=" section-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
            <form class="reservation-form" method="post" action="{{ route('resrvation.reserve') }}">
              {{ csrf_field() }}

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" name="name" id="name" placeholder="  &#xf007;  Name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" id="email" placeholder="  &#xf1d8;  e-mail">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="  &#xf095;  Phone">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" name="dateandtime" id="datetimepicker1" placeholder="&#xf017;  Time">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <textarea type="text" name="message" class="form-control reserve-form empty iconified" id="message" rows="3" placeholder="  &#xf086;  We're listening"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-reservation">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i></span>
                                        Make a reservation
                                    </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```